# Embed Acumatica New Screen page in Website

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to build a Support page for my website which should have Acumatica New Case Screen for customers to create a new Case. I tried using iFrame but when logged in, Selectors and dropdown don't respond. Any Suggestions how do I get New Case screen for my Support page just like in Acumatica Partner's portal.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:
1) Create an acumatica portal web site; Make sure sp203000 page is accessible and works fine.
2) Create a simple html page and assign iframe src to be sp203000 screen url:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
     <style>
        iframe {height:800px; width:1200px;}
     </style>
     <iframe src="http://localhost/AcuPortal/pages/sp/sp203000.aspx?CaseCD=null&CaseClassID=BILLING">
       <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
     </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it works fine:

[New Case form embedded into frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTXmt.png)

First time you will see the login screen in the frame. If you want users to see the form without logging in you need to think about some SSO solution for your site and acumatica.

Comment: Thank you @Viktor, but when the user logs in then the Selectors doesn't work using Iframes

Comment: Try to create an html file and see if it works for you, in my case they were working perfect, may be your site handles requests in some way which breaks them.